# Coupled non-linear first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to solve the following set of equations.
$$
\dot{x}(t) = -kx(t) + a x(t) + b y(t) + c x(t)y(t)\\
\dot{y}(t) = -py(t) - a x(t) - b y(t) - c x(t)y(t)
$$

If $k=p=0$ it can be solved by noting $x+y=const$. In this case, the solutions are monotonous.

The related work I found was the method outlined in https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.14021, which does not apply.

I would appreciate suggestions and references!